# deprecated en adroid studio v4.1 AsyncTask

Tags: java

***tengo este codigo, ya que esta deprecated AsyncTask...***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{ 
    private RecyclerView Recyler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewProductos);
    }

    //AsyncTask deprecated 
    private classPerfomsNetworkRequest extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        String url;

        HashMap<String,String> params;

        int

        PerformNetWorkRequest(String url,HashMap<String,String> params,int requestCode){
            this.url =url;
            this.params = params;
            this.requestCode = requestCode;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try{
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
                if(!object.getBoolean("error)){
                    refreshContenidoList(object.getJSONArray("contenido));
                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids){
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
            if(requestCode == mypojo)
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(url,params);

            if((requestCode= mypojo))
            return requestHandler.sendGetRequest(url);
            return null;

        }   
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hola, es necesario que desarrolles más tu problema ya que no menciona cual es el problema que quieres solucionar. Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta tenga mejor aceptación

Comment: Y ¿Cuál es tu duda o problema con respecto a tu código? Pregunto porque, salvo por el deprecated, no dices algo mas alla de que falla...

Comment: Lo que sucede es que el android lo tuve guardado hace tiempo con ese codigo y cuando lo abro me lanza deprecated  cual seria la solucion de extends AsyncTask y llamar el onPostExecute y  doInBackground